# kibana dashboard limit user access? without xpack

Tags: kibana, elk, xpack

I'm using  ELK stack 7.4 OSS (open source) version.I have already created a dashboard and i want to give 'read only permission' to dashboard to user. But the xpack role creation wasn't working with OSS(Open source) version. Is there and alternative you can suggest?

Comment: For just access permission you can use nginx  restriction rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get user management access in Kibana/Elastic you need to move to xpack based version of the software. In OSS you will not get those features.

Role based access is enabled in the Basic version which is also free. 
https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

You can move to Basic version of the ELK and try out the role based access.